# Ajax call on Cordova ios SecurityError: DOM Exception 18

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, cordova

Hi I'm building an iOS application via Cordova(5.1.1)/Phonegap and I have a problem I can´t solve.

A basic `Ajax` call throws a `SecurityError: DOM Exception 18` I tried all the tricks regarding whitelisting and now I'm lost.. Anyone who can help? Thanks.

Here is what I do after device is ready:

```
    var getUrl = 'http://shopplo.com/api/posts/radius/'+app.lat_min+'x'+app.lat_max+'x'+app.lng_min+'x'+app.lng_max+'';

    //console.log(getUrl);

    var getPosts = $.ajax({
          method: 'GET',
          url: getUrl,
          dataType: 'JSON'
        })
        .done(function(e) {
            console.log( e );


        })
        .fail(function(e) {
            //console.log( "error");

            $.each(e, function(key, element) {
                console.log('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + element);
            });

        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log( "complete" );
        });
```

getUrl is: http://shopplo.com/api/posts/radius/37.11032230061141x73.11032230061141x-20.572796183027627x42.36447502674581

And I get:

```
2015-07-20 01:12:55.981 ShopploLight[779:568632] key: responseJSON :: value: undefined
2015-07-20 01:12:55.983 ShopploLight[779:568632] key: status :: value: 0
2015-07-20 01:12:55.983 ShopploLight[779:568632] key: statusText :: value: Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18
2015-07-20 01:12:55.984 ShopploLight[779:568632] complete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your meta tag.
By default, it uses:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

use the code below to enable all requests

```
<!-- Enable all requests, inline styles, and eval() -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Comment: YES!! That did it.. Thank You Clint.

Comment: This is a MAJOR LIFESAVER. I spent 2-3 hours of searching, trial, and error last week until I discovered this one. I am using and referencing this solution in a blog post (to solve another problem) at: http://www.brodybits.com/cordova/sqlite/api/jquery/2015/10/26/populating-cordova-sqlite-storage-with-the-jquery-api.html

Comment: SECURITY WARNING: as discussed in the [Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/jUw5hdyHoZw) PhoneGap forum topic, this solution turns off all security and is NOT recommended. The CSP tag has already been documented at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist for quite a while. Someone recently made a blog post at: https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md

Answer (score 2):

The above answer errors due to the syntax being incorrect.

Below is correct:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than allowing everything, you could just allow the urls that you are making the ajax call to. For example, if I wanted to get something from the facebook API, I could have something like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src: 'self' https://graph.facebook.com">
```